# How I will set mat checkbox value(checked/unchecked) inside loop, based on API value in angular 8

Tags: angular-material, angular8

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let schedule of this.workScheduleTableData; let i = index"
      (click)="displaySchedule(schedule)">
    <td><mat-checkbox value="{{schedule.partTime}}"
                      [ngModel]="ptCheckBox">P/T</mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From Api side `partTime value=(1,0)`, how i will set checked for 1 and unchecked for 0.

Comment: why not bind ngModel to schedule.partTime and update the partTime property of the elements contained in workScheduleTableData when you get the data from your api ?

Comment: can u give me one example . how i will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the binding of ngModel to **schedule.partTime**, you can control the parttime-property for every entry in your list workSheduleTableData.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let schedule of this.workScheduleTableData; let i = index">
    <td><mat-checkbox value="{{schedule.partTime}}"
                      [ngModel]="schedule.partTime">P/T</mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

so, for example, if you receive data from your backend which should result in setting all parttime-properties to true (hence checking the associated checkboxes), you could do so with the following code:

```
this.workScheduleTableData.forEach( w => w.partTime = true);
```

Comment: this.workScheduleTableData.forEach( w =>{
      if(w.partTime==1){
        w.partTime = true;
      }else{
        w.partTime = false;
      }